# Using javascript can I connect to an MQTT broker once when my site loads and get any incoming messages despite navigating to multiple html/js files?

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I'm running a localhost web application using a combination of html and javascript files.  I have successfully set up a Paho MQTT client in the initial javascript file, which allows me to publish messages to my localhost broker, as well as view in the console all messages published to that broker.  However as soon as I navigate to a new web page, which loads a different javascript file, the client dies and I no longer receive incoming messages.

I have tried to preserve the client object using sessionStorage, but this does not work.

Connecting anew on every javascrpt page load will not work because messages could be coming in constantly and we can't drop them during the re-connection.

I guess I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to a broker outside of the scope of the current javascript file being run, or is the global scope of that current file the ultimate global scope the javascript engine recognizes?

If there is no solution, could I open a window in the background, add all new messages in a queue, and share them with main window?

Comment: As I said on your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114350/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-a-broker-via-javascript-paho-mqtt-when-a-page-first) you probably want to look at re-engineering the site to be effectively a single page.

Comment: You might use a Service Worker and use postMessage to communicate with the pages.

For example, check out https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Comment: Websockets inside a Service Worker should work in Chrome, as per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=671588 (which is fixed)